# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter, database query and NullPointerException

Tags: android, database, sqlite, adapter, android-listview

I'm trying to make ListView populated from database, and spice each row with fancy delete button. So I made list Activity and custom SimpleCursorAdapter.

This is main ListView activity:

```
    public class EditEntries extends ListActivity {
    Cursor cursor;
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    private static String[] FROM = { _ID, SCORE_COLUMN,
            "date(time, 'localtime')", };
    private static int[] TO = { R.id.rowid, R.id.title, R.id.time, };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.entries_list);
        try {
            cursor = getEvents();
            showEvents(cursor);
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
        // Set up data binding
        SMSimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SMSimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.entries_list_item, cursor, FROM, TO);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private Cursor getEvents() {
        db.open();
        cursor = db.getAllScores();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        return cursor;
    }

    void delRow() {        // this is method for deleting row by _id
        db.open();
        db.deleteScore(3); // here will be TAG with _id from adapter,
        db.close();        // for now I just use hardcoded _id
    }

}
```

And this is custom SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
    public class SMSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    
    Cursor c;
    Context context;
    Activity activity;

    public SMSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        
        this.c = c;
        this.context=context;
        this.activity=(Activity) context;
        
    }
    EditEntries dbDel = new EditEntries(); //from previous code sample

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null)
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.entries_list_item, null);
        View row = convertView;
        
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        
        TextView score = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowid);
        
        id.setText(c.getString(0));
        time.setText(c.getString(2));
        score.setText(c.getString(1));
        
        String daTag = c.getString(1);
        
        ImageButton delButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delButton);
        delButton.setFocusable(true);
        delButton.setClickable(true);
        //delButton.setTag(daTag);
        delButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //Click listener fro delete button
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 dbDel.delRow(); //this is "delete row" method from previos code                    sample
             }
             });

        return(row);
    }

}
```

And all this stuff gives me NullPointerException when I click delete button.
I'm new to android, and suppose that I just missed something obvious.

LogCat:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at namespace.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:66)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at namespace.EditEntries.delRow(EditEntries.java:50)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at namespace.SMSimpleCursorAdapter$1.onClick(SMSimpleCursorAdapter.java:64)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2414)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8838)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4680)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14027):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: can you post the `logcat` output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in your SMSimpleCursorAdapter code:

```
EditEntries dbDel = new EditEntries(); //from previous code sample
```

You create a new object but it won't be a managed Activity (eg. the onCreate method won't be called). The NPE probably comes from your DBAdapter when you try to create it the second time (from your Adapter).

Quick fix:

```
EditEntries dbDel; //from previous code sample
public SMSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    this.c = c;
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = (Activity) context;
    this.dbDel = (EditEntries) context;
}
```

---

If you don't want just a quick fix the following would be a much better solution:

1. Move the delRow, getEvents method into your DBAdapter class
2. Modify the constructor of your SMSimpleCursorAdapter to give in the DBAdapter class (created in your ListActivity).

Comment: Yes, as I suspected, the log backed up my theory. Hope my answer helps.